# Dockerfile upgrade postgresql 10 python error

Tags: python, dockerfile

```
ENV PG_MAJOR 10
ENV PG_VERSION 10.1-1.pgdg80+1

RUN echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jessie-pgdg main' $PG_MAJOR > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y postgresql-common \
        && sed -ri 's/#(create_main_cluster) .*$/\1 = false/' /etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf \
        && apt-get install -y \
                postgresql-$PG_MAJOR \
                postgresql-contrib-$PG_MAJOR \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I get the below error in this part:

> dpkg: error processing package python3.5-minimal (--configure): 
>   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
>   status 134 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
>   python3-minimal:  python3-minimal depends on python3.5-minimal (>=
>   3.5.1-2~); however:   Package python3.5-minimal is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure): 
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for
>   libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ... Errors were encountered while
>   processing:  python3.5-minimal  python3-minimal E: Sub-process
>   /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: What's your base image? You didn't mention the `FROM` line.

Comment: The base image is ubuntu

Comment: The `ubuntu` image is not xenial, so it does not use glibc 2.23, as in your example. Please show us the `FROM` line you use.

Comment: Ok shall I use debian base image?
tried to use this one: FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/debian9
please tell me what the required changes.

Comment: *I* would prefer Debian, but this really depends on what you do.  The key is that the base image must be consistent with the PGDG repository you enable and use to install PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong PGDG repository:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jessie-pgdg main
```

This package source is for the Debian jessie distribution, but your system uses [glibc 2.23-0ubuntu10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/glibc).  This suggests your image is a Ubuntu xenial installation, so you should use this instead:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main
```

Comment: Unfortunately still same problem. :(

Comment: Please advice, which base image should I use?